# Using ASP.Net ajax library for cross browser Xml manipulation

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am currently updating a web app that uses ActiveX objects in client side code to manipulate some xml.  Of course, this app only works in IE and I need to get it cross browser compatible.

I am looking to get a javascript xml library to handle the cross browser oddities, and was wondering if the ASP.Net ajax library would work.  I have looked around a bit, but I haven't been able to any examples of loading a fresh xmldom object up using this.  If not, any other good libraries out there I should take a look at?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need XPath or (not the *xor* type of an *or*) XSL-T, than you may be willing to take a look at [Google's AJAXSLT](http://goog-ajaxslt.sourceforge.net/).

I don't know that ASP.NET Ajax library includes any specific XML functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Over a year ago I was facing a similar problem. I decided to take the [JSON](http://json.org) plunge and I've never regretted leaving XML behind. It is an order of magnitude faster and much easier to deal with in JavaScript (and many other languages). Add of the array enhancing powers of something like [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) and you're cookin'.

Sure, there was the one-time pain of converting my data transport from XML to JSON, but it paid for itself rather quickly.